# Facebook comments load endlessly on first pageview in Safari

Tags: facebook, comments, loading, xfbml

I'm having problems with the Facebook Comments Social Plugin not loading comments in Safari on the first load of a page. What happens is the first couple comments show and the loading bar sticks around forever. If the page is refreshed all the comments properly load. Its hard to get them to bug again after the first time you see the issue. It's a problem occurring frequently with Safari users though.

This issues does not happen in Firefox, Chrome, IE, or Opera. Originally I was having problems in Chrome but they seem to have mysteriously stopped occurring recently (even clearing the cache has no effect).

The only weird thing I can think of is that I am manually calling *FB.XFBML.parse();*. Other than that I'm using all of Facebook's code as recommended at the time I implemented it. The problem only started occurring in the last few months.

A screenshot of how it looks when the bug occurs is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0fNF.jpg

When the page is refreshed everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. This was a bug being caused by Google Page Speed. Some of the Facebook scripts were being unintentionally proxied through their service and as a result would break occasionally in some browsers.